# song playing on the speakerphone and on headphone at the same time

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, speakerphone

I'm using this code to select a song :

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`
 `intent.setType("audio/*");`
 `activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a song"),1);`

but when I'm using a headphone, if I select a song, it plays both on the speakerphone and on the headphone...

so, how do I set correctly the sound output, in this case?

thanks!!